# apt-get update issue in Kali

Tags: linux, kali-linux, gnupg, apt

I'm running Kali Linux in WSL2. It's a new installation (using `wsl --install`) but when I try to `apt-get update` I get the following error:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous 
index files will be used. GPG error: http://mirrors.jevincanders.net/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The 
following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  The following signatures 
were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Now I've seen other questions that suggest an `apt-key` command to fix this. However, this throws another error:

```
E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation
```

I can't install gnupg because I haven't run `apt update` yet. What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Which apt-key command did you run? GnuPG should already be installed by default (and indeed the initial output about signatures shows GPG is installed).

Comment: @fuzzydrawings this is the specific one I used: `wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc  | apt-key add`

Comment: if you can't use **apt** may try downloading a compatible version of ***gnupg*** from debian package archive and then install  the downloaded package with **dpkg**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there appears to be issues with Kali Linux WSL (not downloaded from Microsoft Store).

The Kali archive keys appear to be missing and cannot be installed using `apt-add key` since it relies on GnuPG, which cannot be installed using `apt`, since the signatures cannot be verified.

The best solution is the one submitted by Jim which installed the Kali archive keys from a Debian package. Once this is done `apt update` and `apt upgrade` will work.

- Download the Debian package for the Kali archive keys `wget -O kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb`
- Install the Kali archive key package `sudo dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb`
- Update list of available packages from Kali repo `sudo apt update`
- Upgrade the WSL system `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: thank you it works now

Comment: thanks it work actually make sure `--no-check-certificate` so you won't get expiry issue

Answer (score 25):

if you encounter any 404 error messages when trying to download the keyring, please try the following:

## Update 2022

for convenience reasons: the current keyring file changed, use the following commands:

```bsh
# download
wget http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2022.1_all.deb
# install
sudo dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2022.1_all.deb
# remove downloaded file again
rm kali-archive-keyring_2022.1_all.deb
# update
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: So if the download path is compromised, the downloaded package over HTTP (an insecure channel) can be anything. Normally (and specifically requiring a correct archive keyring in the first place) the apt-get command validates the package's checksum against the signed release file. Here nothing such was done. It's about Kali, so "insecure channel" is not something hypothetical.

Comment: The correct way is to have an other correctly installed system and use the results of the dry-run command `apt-get --print-uris reinstall kali-archive-keyring` (doesn't require root) run on that other system: URL + checksum verified against the signed release file.

Answer (score 6):

I did not alter `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I solved the "An error occurred during the signature verification" with the following commands (run from root):

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb

dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb

apt update
```

Comment: This answer is the one that worked for me.  The important difference is that I needed to include `--no-check-certificate` in the wget command.

Comment: this method worked, but I had to download the file using firefox vs wget (with that line)

Answer (score 2):

Manually download and install the needed package to verify the signature:

```bsh
wget https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb
```

Then `apt update` and `apt upgrade` should work as expected.

Comment: Please elaborate a little on what your answer is doing so that everyone can learn a little from it :)

Comment: @fpnick - It downloads and installs the Debian package.

Comment: it worked for me, I just updated the naming from current version here https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/

Answer (score 2):

Adding a bit more to this as there is one extra step needed for me:
Windows 11 WSL kali-linux

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb

dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb

apt update
apt install libcrypt1
apt full-upgrade
apt autoremove
```

Without installing libcrypt1 first, an upgrade will lock you out of Kali.

Comment: for me just installing `libcrypt` locked me out of kali lol.. and nothing fixes it except reinstalling wsl kali...

Comment: you need to `sudo upgrade perl-base` first (which will pull in `libcrypt`) to avoid getting locked out

Answer (score 0):

Weird - the version of Kali downloaded by WSL with `wsl --install` is completely broken and is missing a lot of things. If you want to run Kali on WSL, download it from the Windows Store instead.

Comment: What to do when your organization blocked Microsoft Store? Microsoft itself [recommends](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) to install the distribution then manually.

Comment: The store and the `--install` version are the same, you can verify by manually installing first and going to the Windows Store page, it will say `Open`, not `Get`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows 11 (x64)

#install wsl version 2
C:\> wsl --set-default-version 2

#install kali-linux distribution
C:\> wsl --install --distribution kali-linux

# get keyring 
# https will not work use http
@:~$ wget -O kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb

# use dpkg to install .deb
user@hostname:~$ sudo dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2020.2_all.deb

# apt update&upgrade
user@hostname:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faVlU.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Found this somewhere . Really helped me to update my OLD kali .For 2022

wget -O kali-archive-keyring_2022.1_all.deb http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2022.1_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2022.1_all.deb

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix just run this

`wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/kali-archive-keyring.gpg`

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2024

for convenience reasons: the current keyring file changed, use the following commands:

```bash
# download
wget http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2024.1_all.deb
# install
sudo dpkg -i kali-archive-keyring_2024.1_all.deb
# remove downloaded file again
rm kali-archive-keyring_2024.1_all.deb
# update
sudo apt-get update
```

Updated the answer from kantholy to 2024

Answer (score -1):

To add the Key first we need to download it from the website of the package you are installing. For example, here we are downloading the key file to add repositories for on Kali-rolling.

- Install `wget` if you don’t already have it using:

  > `sudo apt install wget`
- After that use `wget` to download the key using:

  > `wget "link-to download-the-key"`
- The command that worked for me was:

  > `wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc`
- The output from this should look like this:

  > `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`
  >
  > `mQINBE9U1CgBEAChen9+cvBS8ioHoCU6wBbL9jaIk5P7ZkPpjDsovMvimqZaozS8`
  > `fEAZM23gJlFratc+rRllV9hPZmGqhtT50RLDzC3yFOvFnJqAPvpVDO2ipQCVnJDX`
  > `0eWDhT62RDwk+FhjksEDwP7Yc4CgohdGDYQu1zTBSLL5qen3rckCnHF2OnSiKnYM`
  > `8YCIKAYMt4VRArAvivjOMspN+1xy2S8GYXX2felsu3Ir1DXvUIE7b/9sdK6MzBcq`
  > `joDH34OqX6isqAW0+K93lmVN+U4yFMzfEB74UMQNWKg39mCB0K/VfQ89ih4zvF9a`
  > `zENbFzfF0O0h09oHF4ZTaUFeI8JImp/x9FC+LveUyJot9t/xv0HVUd08Y4PgO48C`
  > `iXOTqqqm/DPF0AbHJGpTuonOsKy3/dYhk7Fvsfn02DMds+RKsukBEzypTIIIzMBF`
  > `Uwiq/GaaNRWw6lnOyE4wMmpwRa11QVDDWkMpuOr1tPV7M+EMAhZY7cyHDmRTOFL3`
  > `H0CxYnInis+k1NQikqtLxNrzWdxsXU25BMbEsAQq7aRTs7wpOnUK+yY+qTG/V5nl`
  > `J6II+/CtWJthIef22r8EYX1BQOXRggamy0nxViC3S6kjuU2Lb1qnDb/c7T9hB723`
  > `4T9yrRHJbygTvQD8BJBADgRy7+XInCp01V4nAJZSu20qopEg082SdWK9FwARAQAB`
  > `tCZLYWxpIExpbnV4IFJlcG9zaXRvcnkgPGRldmVsQGthbGkub3JnPokCVQQTAQoA`
  > `PwIbAwYLCQgHAwIGFQgCCQoLBBYCAwECHgECF4AWIQRExlE6jk+z0wh191jtRE/w`
  > `fY0L9gUCYe/xTgUJGD63pgAKCRDtRE/wfY0L9ofUD/9zichMeQ5+XxHnpHTSmUNR`
  > `9eCcis6NGIbW+hTfSxSttfCQBrxKGfYXwVcqGRIiSDp9FcfqH5UsgPOzgJzmLBLV`
  > `i0HfMRDpcCWJzk8VfWde/5Hv0P0XSx/Y+VR7PMJVOzWkF7o0kM4bITx3M5BYY08s`
  > `leoZMNZo9sSR0GdzbXoIXkuBwMG+nw0qjfsyI8Qcsi52Uk8YhdCkgaAb8vYyxMwO`
  > `qKJ6SIIENT6ycyZw4ueFZXZY/RYPJFvWZEYB0cFOMbNwlrXFUZyr4fDdPruaPlZW`
  > `zBIU8jwEE372frdRuXilJ2Q+Me9jhSxvnJegJsHDdgeLU6IDeAiaAaTzvufr3KmA`
  > `YifZ1Q20xDzdN5RZ5x3vNV9cihVb3qizSUe0y6LfpPeIPoa+ENzT4WqhP6rfMMhF`
  > `2KcwhNFP+faB+qs79YqIWnChrJNiE5HQDDgP6DY1ETmjj6Bo+DC9RyasWT5pSJYA`
  > `8rOVJ+1bE4sxlqtvDVlAdR1LwIpHeskz4o/lAMPHSNTX2WBDJdYvhT28xTC3cYlA`
  > `kcdpvBbjj7C4VqgMvsPLg13lfR/A28ADO6AxY323+OpPv6crsDbYOcIBpwBgHb96`
  > `AYyottiEfNnLBCysR/m34TdlYvFW0KDYsbMYLCJH/uzJK3l8TCdVBfkzDMMctSFV`
  > `nFY/xHhDFweArXNHru2CJLkCDQRPVNQoARAAoMOCt6yDngNUawaFLqFzzkQ2UDt1`
  > `LyWMM5qRusYmVW7DbMqRgl816AhW3qGXlpET2QDK/C7np8kiwkx22cWkK2W7e877`
  > `bKGX1jH0k8jIZWxE15pBCBkTk+zb6elC263qiw36jxAlEnwd4eP0OAY6SxD9xi5H`
  > `fJ7zXO+2hF4bVgofRGNmr5IA9SPL0yRJo+dNm3Sh+MhdNMpvJpOdk0PWqq1ZP9LC`
  > `1XCYNtjlImsemugLloKIrdpwAcHJ6XqhyI5IujftmUfN6hL33MAl34Auy/4ElUFU`
  > `9DjvWI7lu+R7P8jdDQB3C10/epbmRu7vqtRNUMf7q+MERZQCPqn75qO8P4zGGHdD`
  > `hVRQjAlefx6ULvhRlLfCkjrSrpnHFGcYLzPXQuxuhSLvZyCnJrG1XmgLB5SAFPxI`
  > `K1oBydqZOYPsPGKZSvMHpBPv9yR2tM6yBjBzBV3/wQCaHD9Yp3sZD9RxSWtAvk3e`
  > `zRjQon81W4S0J6dUZL2mog7gWzDj9v42cIV890ezS077dpeL2fSZOUr3fMrM1ZPf`
  > `JKue8SrvlVVV1wySA6VxBss71iWZNEHC5gD/geC863FaOxXKFZXWxD+MeM/hrUef`
  > `mj67fQ4rjzTgKFRtivmSKzggA3FeOeUCg0gadG9sGH/gfxToA61T/xxEWEyuwJiO`
  > `2SVS/iBjQnfcjDMAEQEAAYkCPAQYAQoAJgIbDBYhBETGUTqOT7PTCHX3WO1ET/B9`
  > `jQv2BQJh7/JiBQkYPri6AAoJEO1ET/B9jQv2cjYQAJIsOLkH0jl09uVIY84TOYru`
  > `4+SMChH6AJklY/600EX8zTBIb0641dsSWk2XyXF+exrlhp/v5ctPb+TbYTDUsQA4`
  > `o2lTJ/rLpUIGJU04tIfA0VMCCyCJAOO1OVpEGU1QwRCQ+NnLDHKdNjvJgF9Y3dpY`
  > `LL388O6BY0tBPF+/DTsoeJLkb6dohJmyk6ls5zi7ZvY2ab1AmwVXBEfYolisla69`
  > `OcGbNrabtpMdd/zdCVxyoHuXaYEuqdMLGbYTDoPI9I2gSBOxIHIJ7z/rHFCDaSSB`
  > `iDDE/+mLZLcbj9pSuQn40ZWEPWELUz1YyjI4bSWYQ/gr5UQhOcNmH1KVULm/s6Sx`
  > `1MBUvWLXFxqb+T7PqWeUAIMTZTjfBiMqJjPzZ61zBBeQDKvciEy/UnunvX+e1cNQ`
  > `1aDzeqaQ3OqJaoFbjmzE218SelQvWCCWQ24ixgQZp8/xd3ae5oQNwqdC0Z6azyMu`
  > `l5dzA+1VxXqlTVZ5gH1/74PZP1YeKPgmSx3LrP3gpOP7Rp99wTZ77b9layR9ZyEP`
  > `IdcIJF0QNSIrKXHjdh5pTqvLhnw58WjGFOhfyA0/YGsV2wbByGuSOAoGEZMg+hs4`
  > `4P3CudqoHQeHZOcflpRwRqheyZc+n2AGxN+RFpvaRV9cs8CiuHyvGHTgq7eear53`
  > `ktZPxNR6/WtX7iCfqkg4`
  > `=3Lxm`
  >
  > `-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`
- After this you should now be able to use `apt` to update without error:

  > `sudo apt-get update`
- This is the quickest and easiest way that I have found to fix this issue as `apt-key add` is deprecated. Everything else I have tried for several hours has returned the same error which is:

  > `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:`
  >
  > `NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6`
  >
  > `Reading package lists... Done`
  >
  > `W: GPG error: https://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease:  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:`
  >
  > `NO_PUBKEY ED444FF07D8D0BF6`
  >
  > `E: The repository 'https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.`
  >
  > `N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`
  >
  > `N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`